# How do you display the Comment field in Query results?

Tags: azure-devops

In Visual Studio Team Services, I'm trying to display text in the comment section of a work item query. Can anyone give me any insight to why the comment field is blank despite adding comments?

I've included a screenshot of my query, and comment side by side.

[Comment section blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdxjt.png)

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gewN0.png]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, "Comments" and "Discussions" are two different Fields they are not the same in VSTS. What you are trying is to display "Comments" from the "Column Options" in the query, but the field that was actually filled/ edited was "Discussions". "Discussions" are only for a Work Item Form. Currently they aren't queryable.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is confusing, because the API documentation says that discussion is deprecated and directs you to comments.  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/history

Comment: Well, you are true the API for Discussion is deprecated. But still they aren't "queryable". Being able to add them to the column options in the "New Query" in VSTS is different from getting the "discussions" data from an API!. :)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the screenshot, the work item is **Task**, there isn’t **Comment** field in Task work item, you can get a work item through [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#fully-expanded) to get the fields.

Regarding Query, you can’t add **Comment** column if you filter Work Item type in Column Options configure window. The Comment filed is in **Review** work item type.

[image]

The **History** column can display the **latest Discussion value** (click Refresh button if it is empty).

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Remarks" field